# php function doesn't returns xml file

Tags: php, xml

I had a function with php that connects on a bd named '****', that don't returns what i need, that's a xml file with the price of a product on a tag, so it returns nothing:

```
function getPVP($codi){
    $query="SELECT preu FROM producte where codi = $codi";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    $xml="<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>".chr(13).chr(10);
    $xml.="<producte>".chr(13).chr(10);

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $xml.="<preu>".$row['preu']."</preu>".chr(13).chr(10);;
    }

    $xml.="</producte>".chr(13).chr(10);

    header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8559-1");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='ws_categories.xml'")
    echo $xml;
}

echo getPVP(3);
```

the xml file returns an error:

```
    This page contains the following errors:

error on line 1 at column 14: String not started expecting ' or "
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

what i'm doing wrong? I don't know what to do, can someone help me with that?

Comment: Change `echo $xml;` to `return $xml;`

Comment: You shouldn't output that header inside your function. You're going to end up regretting that.

Comment: If `$codi` isn't an `int` and it's a string, then change to `where codi = '$codi'";`

Comment: Also, your error isn't in your example code. It's on the first line of your script, y'know, like it says in the error.

Comment: it's an int fred, anthony what header? i put the header out my function?

Comment: Take out the extra `;` at the end of `$xml.="<preu>".$row['preu']."</preu>".chr(13).chr(10);;`

Comment: You're also missing an `;` at the end of `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='ws_categories.xml'")`

Comment: You shouldn't escape the single quotes when it is inside the double quotes. Try removing those backslashes.

Comment: no fred, that's because i copied and miss the ';', because on the php file i have it. but the extra ';' i removed it, so i have the same error :(

Comment: SQL injection paradise.

Comment: yeeeeep! thanks iamsleepy, that's it, i removed the backslashes and the php generates well my xml file :D how i can close this question?

Comment: add an answer iamsleepy, and i accept this answer to close this question u ;D tanks all

Comment: you should call exit after sending headers.

Comment: no prob. but remember. That goes when you use double quotes inside single quotes too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't escape the single quotes when it is inside the double quotes. Try removing those backslashes.

```
$xml="<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf-8\'?>".chr(13).chr(10);
```

to

```
$xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>".chr(13).chr(10);
```

:)